# Replace file() with cUrl in PHP when allow_url_fopen is off

Tags: php, curl

i have a Problem with a script. The Problem is that the server, where the script should run has allow_url_fopen disabled.

However i need this for my script ro run properly.

`$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

I just dont find a proper solution to replace/recreate this solution with cUrl. 
The problem is that file() creates an array, and my php-Knowledge is just not sufficient enough to change this into returning `$lines` as an array

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $filename);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$lines = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split a string into substrings, not keeping the delimiters. Then you just have to filter out the empty lines.

```
// Replace Windows (CRLF) newlines with UNIX (LF) newlines
$text = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $text);

// Split the string at each LF, keeping only non-blank lines
$lines = array();
foreach ( explode( "\n", $text ) as $line ) {
    if ( $line !== '' ) {
        $lines[] = $line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a string into an array of lines using `explode()`:

```
$string = curl_exec($ch);
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
```

To ignore the empty lines, you can use `array_filter()`:

```
$lines = array_filter($lines, function($x) { return $x !== '' ; });
```

It's kind of surprising that they would allow `curl` when they don't `allow_url_fopen`.

Comment: and then check for empty lines

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works after adding the parameters ' curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);'
'curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);' for an SSL Connection.

Comment: I am also curios why curl is allowed and file isnt. Google search brought me here: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/190250-why-is-curl-any-safer-than-file-or-fopen/

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. It's not that they don't want to let you access URLs, it's that they want you to distinguish whether you're accessing files (using fopen and friends) versus URLs (using CURL), and not mix the two modes.

Comment: Yep thats also how i understood it ;) I'm running Typo3 without problems on the server and that also makes a remote connection for the extension repo.